# Hibernate @orderby does not seem to working

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entitities, User and Comment, both of them are POJO's.
Comment has a reference to User.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")  
private User user;  // saves the User's id as a foreign key to Comment table
```

Comment also has a field addedDate which is a Date.

```
@OrderBy
@Column(name = "date_added")
private Date addedDate;
```

When Hibernate retreives the data from the db I want the comments to be ordered by addedDate but sadly it orders by User. 
Even if I annotate the field "addedDate" with @OrderBy (javax.persistence.OrderBy) it does not seem to have any effect.

What I want is this:
userX earlyComment,
userY earlyComment,
userX lateComment,
userY lateComment,

But what I get is this:
userX earlyComment,
userX lateComment,
userY earlyComment,
userY lateComment,

I have seem similar questions here but none of them I found solved my problem.
What Do I do wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you retrieving the comments? Are you doing a query, or are they part of a collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I believe `@OrderBy` annotation should be applicable when you have a `Collection` as a memeber so that oredering can be done on the collection elements.

So adding `@OrderBy` on a foreign key reference is not useful as for a single object ordering doesn't matter.

See [Order By](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html) says

> This annotation specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued association at the point when the association is retrieved.

Now for your solution you need to add order by explicitly clause when you query the DB.

Comment: "Now for your solution you need to add order by explicitly clause when you query the DB."
This is the right way to go.